# Persistent connection across http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have implemented a timer in my web application (which is online test of 1 hour) using javascript. Timer starts from 1 hour and eventually reaches 0. The webpage automatically closes when timer reaches 0. My problem is that i can't rely on javascript for timer because as it is on client side, some malicious user may manipulate the timer. I have thought of following two solutions:

1. I have thought of using ajax to check after every fixed interval that whether server timer (i would be running a parallel timer on server) and client timer are in sync or not. But every ajax call would mean a separate http hit on server which is not optimal.
2. I have thought of using nodeJS to maintain a persistent connection but the issue is that that when next question loads, web sockets connection will have to be recreated.

Is there any way to maintain persistent connection across the http hits.

Comment: Store timestamp in Database, calculate on load?

Comment: You can use socket.io where the connection will persist across questions

Comment: you don't need to persist any connections, you just need to checkin and checkout and compare those timestamps on a backend before acting on the finish (or anything).